# MongoDB/Doctrine not unsetting fields when null or empty array is set

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table in `MongoDB` with xml schema similar to the below:

```
...
<field name="fieldNameA" type="string" />
<reference-many field="fieldNameB" target-document="RelatedObject" strategy="set" />
...
```

If I update these records everything works fine, unless I try to unset the values. i.e.

```
$object->setFieldNameA(null);
$object->setFieldNameB([]);
```

In this instance when I call `persist` and `flush` on the object the two original values remain in the database. I would expect/want these properties to be unset in the collection.

I have tried including `nullable="true"` for the string field and I have tried changing the strategy used on the referenced object, however neither updates have had any impact. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: MongoDB version = 2.6.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Turned out that first I had to make this document managed by Doctrine. Was enough to select it by id from database. Only then Doctrine was removing the null values and empty collections.